# How do I save my user settings so that when the GUI exits and then returns, it stays as how saved

Tags: java

I would like my user to be able to save their settings, but I do not know how to save the information  chosen so that if they exited the settings GUI and then returned, the settings would be saved to the way  set. I am using a text file at the moment but there must be a more efficient way of doing this.

I am aware that there are similar questions but I am either finding the answers too complex or too vague.

Comment: I think this question is too vague.

Comment: if there's a checkbox, you save the state of the checkbox. if there's radio buttons, you save which radio buttons are selected, blah blah blah. there's no magic to it.

Comment: sorry I'll try again, there is a start GUI with options of different settings, such as "movie settings", you click the button and then a new GUI pops up giving you options to change settings, then when you click "save and exit", you return to the start GUI. You cannot save the state as when you leave the GUI and return, it goes back to it's original setting

Answer (score 0):

For a simple fix, not really sure how efficient, you could create a text/property file that saves the appropriate settings. When the program opens it loads the settings from this file.